# How to make 'ctrl+click' on visual studio code with macOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code on mac and looking for trying to set 'ctrl+click' function for "go to definition".

First of all, I have tried to do: keyboard shortcuts -> search "go to definition" --> right click --> change keybinding from F12 to ctrl+x (because I don't know how to set the 'click' mouse command in that visual studio code setting) but doesn't work.

Someone who has the same problem should help me, please? It will be helpful for me and for my code :)

thank you for anyone who will resolve this trouble.

Answer (score -1):

For that, there's a site where you will get VScode plugins.  You can install "MouseNavigation" plugin from VScode marketplace and can set custom mouse gestures controls and that's it. Try searching for the VScode plugin on Google.

Comment: Hi Anna! Thank you for your reply, but MouseNavigation plugin for VScode doesn't exist. do you have any other advice to give me? thank a lot!